# Get XPath Position Predicates from Nodes

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing, domxpath

Is there a way, to get the XPath positional predicates from a certain instance of a node. So i search for a position(Node) function, which returns the position of a node in a dom tree.
Example:

```
<page>
  <line>
    <wd> bla </wd>
    <wd> blabla </wd>
  </line>
  <line>
    <wd> lorem </wd>
    <wd> ipsum </wd>
    <wd> dolor </wd>
    <wd> sit </wd>
  </line>
</page>
```

So the function applied on the node with the content "ipsum" should return something like: second word, second line, first page.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the position of a node using the `preceding-sibling` axis. For example, if the `wd` element containing the string `'ipsum'` is in variable `$ipsum`, you can the position within its parent element with:

```
count($ipsum/preceding-sibling::*) + 1
```

And the position of the parent of `$ipsum` with:

```
count($ipsum/../preceding-sibling::*) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't get it. The string could not be unique?! So i would get multiple Positions. How can i access the information of a node object? Also i'm not able to implement the rest of your example :( in which context i have to use the count function? ... thanks again

Comment: You're using one XPath expression for fetching the node, afterwards you will use this node to query its "position" with follow-up XPath expressions. Possibly replace $ipsum by the context `.`. Heavily depends on which programming language you are using.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Java together with org.w3c.dom and i still don't get, how to do :( With object has the count function?